# What is the grpc proto for golang const?

Tags: go, enums, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

If I have the golang

```
type Animal string
const (
  Cat   Animal = "cat"
  Dog   Animal = "dog"
  Mouse Animal = "mouse"
)
```

How should I write the proto? If I use enums I will then need to manually map across myself?

```
enum Animal {
  CAT = 0;
  DOG = 1; 
  MOUSE = 2;
}
```

Comment: proto enums will be compiled to Go consts with `int32` type. Perhaps you're asking how to generate consts with `string` type? (spoiler: not possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access dynamically like:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    pb "animal"
)
```

```golang
func main() {
    type Animal string
    const (
        Cat   Animal = "CAT"
        Dog   Animal = "DOG"
        Mouse Animal = "MOUSE"
    )
    
    myProtoAnimal := pb.Animal(pb.Animal_value[string(Cat)])

    fmt.Printf("%T=%v", myProtoAnimal, myProtoAnimal)

}
```

Will print

```
animal.Animal=CAT
```